# If the system is in state j, what is the probability of selecting a white ball?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, random-variables, markov-chains

**STATEMENT:** We have two boxes, and each contains $m$ balls (in total $2m$). Out of $2m$ balls, $m$ are red and $m$ are white. In a repetitive experiment, a ball is simultaneously selected from each box and is moved to the other box. Let’s define the states $j = 0, 1, . . . ,m$ as the first box containing $j$ white balls.

**QUESTION:** If the system is in state j, what is the probability of selecting a white ball?

**MY WORKING:**

Let $j=0$, then the probability of selecting a white ball is $\frac{0}{m}=0$

In the same way;

Let $j=1$, then the probability of selecting a white ball is $\frac{1}{m}$

.

.

.

For $j=m$, we have the probability of selecting the white ball to be $\frac{m}{m}=1$

So if the system is in state $j$, the general probability of selecting white ball will be $\frac{j}{m}$.

Are my calculations correct? I am not sure about them. If they are wrong, can anyone help me correct them? I will really appreciate it.

Thanks

Comment: you are picking one ball each from both boxes. If at least one of the balls has to be white then find the probability that both are black. If exactly one ball has to be white then find the probability of $WB$ and $BW$ (both will be same).

Comment: @MathLover I didn't get you. Can you elaborate a bit?

Comment: If you mean to ask: "is in state $j$ the probability of drawing a white ball *from the first box* $\frac{j}m$?" then the answer is "yes". But is that really what you want to ask? Is there no part to play for the other box an the other drawn ball?

Comment: @drhab there is nothing said about other box in the Question. But yes, there are $3$ parts to the given Question. Part $(i)$ is what I have solved and asked to confirm whether I am correct or not. The part $(ii)$ on the other hand asks "If the system is in state $j$, what is the probability of selecting a red ball?", part $(iii)$ is asking "Write the transition probabilities and the equations to calculate the steady-state probabilities for $j$". That's it. Nothing said about other box at all.

Comment: @drhab.
I need a bit guidance in remaining parts as well. I have solved part $(ii)$ and concluded that there is $0$ probability of selecting red ball. It is because we are talking about first box containing $j$ white balls (given in the STATEMENT part). Am I correct on this one too?

Comment: as for part $(iii)$ I don't know to how to do it. I will appreciate your help and guidance, if you have few minutes. Thanks

Comment: Concerning (ii) there are $m-j$ red balls in the first box, right? So the probability of drawing a red ball from this box is $\frac{m-j}{m}$. I don't understand why you go for $0$. And is it not possible that with "what is the probability of selecting a red ball?" they think of drawing two balls and actually want the probability that at least one of them is red?

Comment: @drhab thanks. How about part $(iii)$. Can you guide in this last one too?

Comment: If you are in state $j$ and two balls are drawn and switched from box then - if $0<j<m$ - the next state will be $j-1$ or $j$ or $j+1$. I think you must find the corresponding probabilities on that. This also for the special cases $j=0$ and $j=m$ with only two possibilities. I think these are what they call the transition probabilities. If $p(j,n)$ denotes the probability that after $n$ switches you are in state $j$ then $p(j,n)$ will converge by growing $n$. I suspect that the limit is the "steady state" probability for state $j$.